# Multiway stable partition

Tags: cuda, partitioning, thrust

Is there a way to perform multiway (>2) stable partition in *Thrust*?
Either stable partition or stable partition copy both are equally interesting. Currently I can only use two-way [stable partition copy](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__partitioning_ga9393578bd1417f5335f700730596fc9c.html#ga9393578bd1417f5335f700730596fc9c) for purposes described above. It is clear how to use it to partition a sequence into a three parts using two predicates and two calls of `thrust::stable_partition_copy`. But I am  sure it is technically possible to implement multiway stable partition.

I can imagine the following *multiway stable partition copy* (pseudocode):

```
using F = float;

thrust::device_vector< F > trianges{N * 3};
// fill triangles here

thrust::device_vector< F > A{N}, B{N}, C{N};
auto vertices_begin = thrust::make_tuple(A.begin(), B.begin(), C.begin());

using U = unsigned int;
auto selector = [] __host__ __device__ (U i) -> U { return i % 3; };

thrust::multiway_stable_partition_copy(p, triangles.cbegin(), triangles.cend(), selector, vertices_begin);
```

`A.begin()`, `B.begin()`, `C.begin()` should be incremented individually.

Also, I can imagine hypothetical *dispatch iterator*, which would do the same (and would be more useful I think).

Comment: if, as you say, "...I am sure it is technically possible to implement multiway stable partition", then haven't you answered your own question?

Comment: I have no such an implementation

Comment: So what is your question then?

Comment: What about stable_sort with a custom comparator which sorts by the return values of your selector?

Comment: @AbatorAbetor I want `O(N)` not `N*log(N)`.

Comment: @talonmies the question is indicated by question mark.

Comment: The question is as narrow as possible. If you don't familiar with the problem field, please, do not vote to close.

Comment: Even `N*log(M)`, where `M` is the number of outputs is suboptimal.

Answer (score 2):

From my knowledge of the thrust internals, there is no readily adaptable algorithm to do what you envisage.

A simple approach would be to extend your theoretical two pass three way partition to `M-1` passes using a smart binary predicate, something like

```
template<typename T>
struct divider
{
   int pass;
   __host__ __device__ divider(int p) : pass(p) { };
   __host__ __device__ int classify(const T &val) { .... };
   __host__ __device__  bool operator()(const T &val) { return !(classify(val) > pass); };

}
```

which enumerates a given input into M possible subsets and returns true if the input is in the Nth or less subset, and then a loop

```
auto start = input.begin();
for(int i=0; i<(M-1); ++i) {
   divider pred<T>(i);
   result[i] = thrust::stable_partition(
                         thrust::device,
                         start, 
                         input.end(),
                         pred);
   start = result[i];
}
```

[ note all code written in a browser on a tablet while floating on a boat in the Baltic. Obviously never compiled or run. ]

This will certainly be the most space efficient, as a maximum of `len(input)` temporary storage is required, whereas a hypothetical single pass implementation would require `M * len(input)` storage, which would quickly get impractical for a large `M`.

Edit to add that now I'm back on land with a compiler, this seems to work as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/partition.h>

struct divider
{
   int pass;
   __host__ __device__ 
   divider(int p) : pass(p) { };
   __host__ __device__ 
   int classify(const int &val) { return (val % 12); };
   __host__ __device__  
   bool operator()(const int &val) { return !(classify(val) > pass); };

};

int main()
{
   const int M = 12;
   const int N = 120;

   thrust::device_vector<int> input(N);
   thrust::counting_iterator<int> iter(0);
   thrust::copy(iter, iter+N, input.begin());

   thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator result[M];
   auto start = input.begin();
   for(int i=0; i<(M-1); ++i) {
      divider pred(i);
      result[i] = thrust::stable_partition(
                            thrust::device,
                            start, 
                            input.end(),
                            pred);
      start = result[i];
   }

   int i = 0;
   for(auto j=input.begin(); j!=input.end(); ++j) {
      if (j == result[i]) {
          i++;
          std:: cout << std::endl;
      }
      std::cout << *j << "  ";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

---

```
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_52 -o partition partition.cu
$ ./partition 

0  12  24  36  48  60  72  84  96  108  
1  13  25  37  49  61  73  85  97  109  
2  14  26  38  50  62  74  86  98  110  
3  15  27  39  51  63  75  87  99  111  
4  16  28  40  52  64  76  88  100  112  
5  17  29  41  53  65  77  89  101  113  
6  18  30  42  54  66  78  90  102  114  
7  19  31  43  55  67  79  91  103  115  
8  20  32  44  56  68  80  92  104  116  
9  21  33  45  57  69  81  93  105  117  
10  22  34  46  58  70  82  94  106  118  
11  23  35  47  59  71  83  95  107  119
```